# Knockout and Asp.net MVC sending json

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, json, knockout.js

I try sending Knockout Model to Asp.net MVC, but all I get is empty object. Fiddler shows me the data is sent correctly.

```
// model
function ProductModel() {
var self = this;
self.Price = ko.observable();
self.Name = ko.observable("");
self.Description = ko.observable("");
self.Discount = ko.computed(function () {
    return self.Price() - ((15 * self.Price()) / 100);
});
}

// viewmodel

function ProductVM() {
var self = this;
self.Product = new ProductModel();
self.Products = ko.observableArray();
self.AddPrd = function () {

    self.Products.push(self.Product);
    dt.row.add([
        $("#ProductName").val(),
        $("#Description").val(),
        $("#Price").val(),
        $("#discount").val()
    ]).draw();

    self.Product = new ProductModel();  

}
self.submit = function () {
    var Data = JSON.stringify(ko.toJS(self.Products));
    console.log(Data);

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AddMultiProducts",
        data: Data,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json'
    });     
}
}
```

c# Model:

```
    public class Product
    {
    public string Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double Discount { get; set; }    
    }
```

c# action:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddMultiProducts(Product prdlist)
    {...}
```

The object sent as displayed in the browser console.log:
         [{"Price":"334","Name":"fdgdfg","Description":"fdgdfg","Discount":283.9}]

Any idea would be great!

Comment: Your `console.log` shows an **array** but your controller action takes a **single** `Product`...

Comment: Something doesn't seem right. Why is the method AddMultiProducts but only accepts one product? Shouldn't it accept an array/list of products?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
self.submit = function () {
    var Data = ko.toJS(self.Products)[0];
    console.log(JSON.stringify(Data));

    $.ajax({
        url: "/Home/AddMultiProducts",
        data: Data,
        type: 'POST',
    });     
}
```

You should not need to stringify the data into JSON or to make it a dataType json request. The above should POST up to the action just fine. Also like the comments state, you want the controller to receive a single object, not an array with a single entry.

Comment: Thank you!! I tried var Data = ko.toJS(self.Products[0]); and didnt understood why it doesnt work ...

Comment: @user1223457 `ko.toJS(self.Products[0])` does not work because `self.Products` is not a javascript array, it is a knockout `observableArray`. You have to convert it to a normal javascript array before you can do normal javascript array stuff (like `[index]`, `.push(item)`, etc.)